# Detecting pedestrian crossing light 'Green man' using feature detection

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, surf

I'm working on a project that should use video or a picture taken from the iphone camera to detect whether the 'green man' or 'red man' is lit at a pedestrian crossing.

So far I have experimented with image masking, contours and feature detection.

The last program I wrote does the following.

1. Zooms into a ROI of the camera image to get a better view of the pedestrian light (it is more of a ROI crop)
2. conducts image masking to only expose green colour
3. Uses feature detection (SURF descriptor and extractor & FLANN based matching) to match the image to a loaded template.

Here is my code:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/n5ck45tige2jgb9/X1DgVPdpPb
Please press ZOOM first and then MATCH.

As you might find out, when the green man is present(Puggs.jpeg) in the image, the match is quite good and I can set a threshold on the number of 'good matches' and find out whether the green man was detected. But if you use and image such as (IMG_0948.jpeg ) there are still matches to random things which makes it difficult to really find out whether a 'green man' was detected by relying on good matches.

The robustness of the matching is my main hurdle right now. Do you have any suggestions or direction?. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about searching for the red man as well - if you can see him then you know you won't be able to see the green; if both detection routines have fairly low false negatives, then you are reduced to the point in time between green flashes; which you probably want to assume *not green* for anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Oliver.The main problem i'm having is robustly matching the green man (or even the red man). when using the green man as the template,the feature detection and matching shows good matches even when no green man is present (its matching to random unmasked areas of the 'scene' image) .If i set a threshold on 'good matches' this would sometimes give me a false result('greenMan found'). This would be the case even if i was looking for the red man.